# The global dimension of fields

Tags: set-theory, homological-algebra, axiom-of-choice

In the absence of the Axiom of Choice, it is not necessarily true that all vector spaces over a field have bases.

> What are the possible global dimensions of fields in a model of ZF in which AoC does not hold?

For comparison, a related result of Osofsky is that the global dimension of a countable product of fields is $k+1$ if $2^{\aleph_0}$ is $\aleph_k$, so that dimension depends on how badly the Continuum Hypothesis fails in one's model of set theory.

Comment: Which definition of global dimension do you use? I think that the equivalence between the usual definitions/characterizations might need AC.

Comment: The least upper bound on the length of projective resolutions of modules!

Comment: (Fields are von Neumann regular and noetherian. Normally, such a thing is semisimple, but I don't know if the proof of this carries over to a non-AoC situation)

Comment: Need there even be enough projectives without Choice? I don't see why an infinitely generated free module need be projective, in particular.

Comment: Presumably the reduction to finitely generated modules uses choice?

Comment: Mariano, is there somewhere to read about the basic definitions related to global dimensions of fields? (I'm not even sure what you mean by "a countable product of fields").

Comment: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1997458?uid=3739832&uid=2460338175&uid=2460337855&uid=2&uid=4&uid=83&uid=63&uid=3739256&sid=21102522485017 might be relevant.

Comment: @JeremyRickard, indeed, that is an issue: it might well be that if there are enough projectives then AC holds, for example.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, there is not much to be read about globgal dimension of fields because in the presence of choice there is not much to be said! For information about global dimension, a introductory book on homological algebra should have most useful results (Weibel, Rotman, &c)

Comment: @Jeremy, Mariano: I don't know if it's relevant, but if there are enough projective in the category of Abelian groups then there is a set forcing which restores the axiom of choice. And the axiom of choice is in fact equivalent to the assertion that every free Abelian group is projective.

Comment: @Mariano: Well, I'm not going to read a whole book now. Do you have a slightly more specific reference to these books? In particular the exact definitions (and perhaps some basic examples for the concepts of global dimensions)?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, the books I mentioned have a whole chapter entitled «Homological dimension» and a section called «Dimensions», respectively, and rather good indices: I was confident in your abilities to find in them the relevant part!

Comment: @Mariano: I'm still in trauma from the course in commutative and homological algebra. ;-)

Comment: @Mariano: When you say a countable product of fields, do you mean that that as a ring structure? Are there limitations on those fields? If so, how does that relate to your question? Are you asking on a particular field, or on products of the same flavor? (I am still in the process of understanding Rotman's chapter, but that's besides the point for now.)